# Firefox Addon - install.rdf - What does the "em" mean in <em:description>...</em:description>

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon

What does the `em` mean in

```
<em:description>...</em:description>
```

This is an extract from a firefox addon `install.rdf` file. I am curious as to what the `em` part adds to this. I could not find a solution to this on Google either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`em` is the XML namespace that contains the `description` element. At the top of the install.rdf file you should see an attribute like this:

```
xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"
```

This tells an XML parser that the prefix `em` is bound to that URI. It's what gives that particular `description` element meaning, and it's how XML documents are able to have multiple `description` elements that don't conflict (by tying each type of `description` to a different URI).